# Runtime error '1004': application or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Runtime error '1004': application or object defined error

Hey I cant find out why my code isn't working. I know it's somewhere in the right hand side of the formula. I've highlighted the error for you.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'accept button

Blank:

machine = TextBox1.Value
rates = TextBox2.Value
    If machine = "" Then 'if blank
        MsgBox ("Please type in a machine name.")
        GoTo DONE
    ElseIf rates = "" Then 'if rates is blank
        MsgBox ("Please type in a rate for machine.")
        GoTo DONE
    End If
For i = 1 To 50 'search database
    If LCase(Worksheets("database").Cells.Range("B2").Offset(0, i)) = LCase(machine) Then 'if name is in database
        MsgBox (machine & " is already in database. Choose another name.")
        GoTo DONE
    ElseIf IsEmpty(Worksheets("database").Cells.Range("B2").Offset(0, i)) Then 'if it's not
        Range("B:B").Offset(0, i).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Worksheets("database").Cells.Range("B2").Offset(0, i) = machine
        Worksheets("database").Cells.Range("B2").Offset(0, i).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        Worksheets("database").Cells.Range("B2").Offset(-1, i) = rates
        For j = 1 To 50
            If LCase(Range("A1").Offset(j, 0)) = "total hours" Then
                ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Offset(j, i).Formula = "=sum(" & Range(Cells(3, i + 2), Cells(j, i + 2)).Address(False, False) & ")"


ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Offset(1 + j, i).Formula = "=product(sum(" & ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, i + 2), Cells(j, i + 2)).Address(False, False) & "," & ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2 + i)) & ")"


                GoTo Cancel
                End If
            Next j
        GoTo Cancel
    End If


Next i
Cancel:

DONE:
End Sub
```

the line that i separate from the others is the one in question.

Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis for the SUM part.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post the exact formula you expect in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know without a description of what you are trying to do.  But perhaps:

```
"=product(sum(" & ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, I + 2), Cells(J, I + 2)).Address(False, False) & "," & ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2 + I).Address & "))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze each part of the line by itself to see what is causing the error. Then put them together after verifying the parts.

```
Dim HoursRangeAddress As String
Dim RateRangeAddress As String

HoursRangeAddress = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, i + 2), Cells(j, i + 2)).Address(False, False)
RateRangeAddress = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i + 2).Address

Debug.Print HoursRangeAddress
Debug.Print RateRangeAddress

ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Offset(1 + j, i).Formula = _
    "=product(sum(" & HoursRangeAddress & ")," & RateRangeAddress & ")"
```

You were missing a parenthesis ) after your sum. But also this caused an error: `ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2 + i))` Try this instead: `ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2 + i).Address`

**Using R1C1 Notation:** You should really learn R1C1 notation. Once you are familiar with it, your code is much easier to write and read. You can replace all of the lines of code above with this one line:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Offset(1 + j, i).FormulaR1C1 = "=R1C*R[-1]C"
```

I understand now that you are trying to multiply the rate in row one by the total hours one row above this formula.

It's so much better to use R1C1 notation in a situation like this. You can avoid entirely the need to create string addresses for the formulas. Your formula becomes very simple and easy to read.

Comment: If this answer is helpful click the checkmark on the left to accept as the answer. Also if you like, you can upvote it.